# Remove existing outline of text color on a GIMP 2.8.14 image

Tags: color, gimp

Trying to change existing text on a book cover from blue to a different color, yet the blue remains along the outline of the letters.
Thanks

Comment: Please describe what you did to change the blue, this helps others to suggest a better approach.

Comment: Using magic wand (fuzzy select) to highlight each letter than bucket fill with new color.

Comment: Welcome, Barbara. A reference picture could be useful, there are several approach to this problem. For example you can [grow](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-selection-grow.html) and [feather](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-selection-feather.html) a little the selection before fill it. Or you can fill the selection in a new layer and [bend](http://docs.gimp.org/2.6/en/gimp-concepts-layer-modes.html) it. Or...

Comment: Paolo Gibellini you hung the moon!  Thank you for the simple Select then "grow" edit. My text is now perfect.

Comment: I'm glad! If you want, you can write yourself an answer for your question, it could be helpful for other people.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to change a range of colors is the Rotate Colors filter: http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-rotate-colormap.html

One of the common tasks people use that for is "how do I change the color of the car in a photo?", and you'll get very decent results in seconds.